How to Update UI Without Page Reload in Ionic-Angular?
[![enter image description here][1]][1]# [![My App UI]

I'm building an app using Ionic and Angular, and I'm trying to update the UI in real-time without triggering a full page reload. Currently, when certain changes occur, the UI only updates after I reload the page. I want the UI to respond immediately when page is started

For example, when a user performs an action, a value or component should update in the view automatically without reloading the entire page. How can I achieve this in Ionic-Angular?
What I have tried:
Calling ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges() to force the update, but this seems inefficient and doesn’t always work as expected.
Any advice on best practices or efficient ways to solve this issue would be appreciated!

Angular provides a reactive programming model that can help you update the UI seamlessly. You can utilize Observables and Subjects from the rxjs library to manage state changes and update the UI accordingly. Use the search function to find numerous posts on how to do this.
